# Thymeleaf form can't handle org.bson.Document type

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity class with fields of type `org.bson.Document`. These are values that I am not allowed to modify, but when using Spring Data I need to map them in my model class so that after saving the document back to Mongo these values won't be lost. So the document is fetched from Mongo, mapped to a `User` POJO and then passed to a Thymeleaf form. When I try to send Thymeleaf form back to the controller I get 400 Bad Request "Validation failed for object..." error and I know it's because of these two additional `Document` fields. How can I pass these fields to Thymeleaf and then back to the controller? They aren't modified in the form, just appear as hidden inputs:

```
<input id="resetPassword" th:field="${user.resetPassword}" type="hidden"/>
<input id="consents" th:field="${user.consents}" type="hidden"/>
```

And my `User` class:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    private SecurityLevel securityLevel = SecurityLevel.LOW;
    private Timestamp created = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
    private Boolean blocked = false;

    private org.bson.Document resetPassword;
    private org.bson.Document consents;
}
```

Comment: You need a way to parse your string passed by thymeleaf to your Document

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the object is being successfully injected into the Thymeleaf template, but not parsed correctly in Spring when the form is returned.

You should examine the representation in the web page (expecting json?) and then ensure that you have a handler defined in Spring that can successfully deserialise the returned object.

If the Document type does not have a conventional constructor (no-args or all-args), or some of the fields are 'hidden' (without the standard getXxx and setXxx methods), then Spring will not be able to reconstruct the object when the form is submitted without a custom handler.

Similarly, if there are not getters for all of the fields (And sub fields) of the object, the Thymeleaf template will have an incomplete object embedded that will not upload correctly.

Take a look at this blog post for some further info: https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/spring-mvc-json-serialization/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a custom `Formatter` like that:

```
public class BsonDocumentFormatter implements Formatter<Document> {

    @Override
    public Document parse(String s, Locale locale) throws ParseException {

        return Document.parse(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Document document, Locale locale) {

        return document.toJson();
    }
}
```

And then I registered it in my `WebMvcConfigureruration`:

```
@Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new BsonDocumentFormatter());
    }
```